timesfm module - TypeError: TimesFmBase.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_len'
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timesfm as tf

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", parse_dates=["Datetime"])
df = df.set_index("Datetime")

tfm = tf.TimesFm(
    context_len=128,  
    horizon_len=5,    
    input_patch_len=32,
    output_patch_len=128,
    num_layers=20,
    model_dims=1280,
    backend="gpu",  
)

I recive back despite is the standard instruction were officially given:
TypeError: TimesFmBase.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_len'


what's your version of timesfm ? pip list | grep timesfm ?

timesfm 1.2.3 on py 3.10.11.1
